Simple derivative computation for time dependent function
Let $F:\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function. Consider the function $G:\mathbb{R}^m\times \mathbb{R}^m\times (0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$G(u,v,t)=F\left(\dfrac{u-v}{t}\right)$$
Consider $\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial t}\vert_{(u_0, v_0, t_0)}$. From my understanding this should be $$\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial t}\vert_{(u_0, v_0, t_0)}=-\dfrac{1}{t_0^2}(u_0-v_0)\cdot dF_{\frac{u_0-v_0}{t_0}}$$ which is a scalar, which makes sense.
Then if we pick tangent vectors $\xi_1, \xi_2, \tau$ in the three tangent spaces $T_{u_0}\mathbb{R}^m, T_{v_0}\mathbb{R}^m, T_{t_0}I$ respectively then how do I write -- $$dG_{u_0,v_0,t_0}(\xi_1, \xi_2, \tau)=\left(1/t_0 dF_{\frac{u_0-v_0}{t_0}}(\xi_1), -1/t_0 dF_{\frac{u_0-v_0}{t_0}}(\xi_2), -1/t_0^2(u_0-v_0)\cdot dF_{\frac{u_0-v_0}{t_0}}\right)$$
I'm having issues with understanding the $\frac{\partial G}{\partial t}\lvert_{u_0, v_0, t_0}$ component. I don't see where the $\tau$ factor comes in, and also how to understand where the object  $\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial t}\vert_{(u_0, v_0, t_0)}$ lies? Is it an element of $T^*I$? Any clarifications will be appreciated. Thank you.

What is a one-form on the real numbers? It is just a linear map of the form $\tau \mapsto c \tau$. This $c$ is what you are computing in the last component, so you just have to multiply that one with $\tau$.
